# Casting @@IDENTITY to Long (Int32) in an Access SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, casting, identity

**I want to use this syntax but I cant:**

```
Select (Clng ( @@IDENTITY ) )
Or
Clng ( select ( @@IDENTITY ) )
```

**I want to get last inserted id in current scope and cast it to the Long type..how can I make this in one query?**

..
This query worked correctly:

```
Select @@identity
```

And give me the last inserted autonumber in current session but I want to cast it to the something else in one query

Comment: Do you get an error or what is the problem?

Comment: I got a syntax error on both of them.

Answer (score 0):

In the **first** query , You are converting a value into long while you are retrieving it, which is a valid operation.

When you use **second** query , when select statement is used, you are getting a record set and not an single value.

```
You can not apply clng on result set but you can apply on a single value
```

**Updated Code:**

*Check the sample code below:*

```
string query = "Insert Into Categories (CategoryName) Values (?)";
string query2 = "Select @@Identity";
long ID;
string connect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
{
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
  {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", Category.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandText = query2;
    ID = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  }
}
```

***I just gave the C# version of code as i was not much aware of VB or VB.Net . More over , methodology is the same***

Comment: Yes u right..but how can I achieve that? How can I get last inserted autonumber and cast it in one query? I want this to use in dapper extension for ms access